# expandlelistview child click

Tags: android, onclick, fragment, expandablelistview

I have an expandle listview witha few children. If i click a child i want it to open it own activity. Right now i got it to work to go to 1 activity only. So when for example when i click on Mambo beach i want it to open an activity with the information of Mambo beach. And when i click on Avis car Rental it should open that acitivity

below my example:

public class TodoFragment extends Fragment {

```
public TodoFragment(){}

ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
List<String> listDataHeader;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_todo,container, false);
}
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // get the listview
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

    // preparing list data
    prepareListData();

    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getActivity(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);


    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    // Listview Group click listener
    expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, long id) {
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            // "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
            // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }
    });

    // Listview on child click listener
    expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            //You have to create next activity say NextActivity.java
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class); 
            startActivity(intent);
            return false;
        }
    });

}

/*
 * Preparing the list data
 */
private void prepareListData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    // Adding group data
    listDataHeader.add("Culture");
    listDataHeader.add("Beaches");
    listDataHeader.add("Car Rental");
    listDataHeader.add("Dinner");

    // Adding child data
    List<String> culture= new ArrayList<String>();

    culture.add("Grotten van Hato");
    culture.add("Ostrich Farm");
    culture.add("Shete Boka national Park");
    culture.add("Landhuis Knip");
    culture.add("Christoffelpark");
    culture.add("Navy Museum");
    culture.add("Post Museum");

    List<String> beaches = new ArrayList<String>();
    beaches.add("Mambo Beach");
    beaches.add("Knip");
    beaches.add("Playa Kalki");
    beaches.add("Westpunt");
    beaches.add("Boca Santa Cruz");
    beaches.add("Cas Abao");
    beaches.add("Playa PortoMari");
    beaches.add("Kontiki Beach");
    beaches.add("Jan Thiel Beach");

    List<String> car = new ArrayList<String>();
    car.add("budget rental");
    car.add("Avis Rental");
    car.add("Alamo Car Rental");
    car.add("Noordstar Rental");
    car.add("Europa Rental");

    List<String> dinner = new ArrayList<String>();
    dinner.add("Truk di Pan");
    dinner.add("Burger King");
    dinner.add("Punda Food");

 // Header, Child data
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), culture); 
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), beaches);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), car);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(3), dinner);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could implement this by simply creating, and launching, a different `Intent` based on the value of `childPosition`. For example:

```
switch (childPosition)
{
    case 0:
        Intent intentChild0 = new Intent(yourMainActivity.this, ActivityForChild0.class); 
        startActivity(intentChild0);
        break;

    case 1:
        Intent intentChild1 = new Intent(yourMainActivity.this, ActivityForChild1.class); 
        startActivity(intentChild1);
        break;

    //Etc...

    default:
        break;
}
```

Adding this to your `OnChildClickListener` will cause a different `Activity` to be launched depending on what child was clicked.

Comment: Thank you, i am going to try this. I am new to android and development

Comment: I made some changes to what you wrote because eclipse was giving some problems. I put for yourMainActivity.this getActivity() this fixed the problem in eclipse then it told me to declare the activity. I did this aswell. Now it is telling me the following Unable to instantiate activity componentInfo. Can you help me with this please

Comment: Hi I found out that i am using Fragments. Is there a way to make a child open a fragment

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions: one is switch the child position and redirect the activity.But this solution has a problem, because you will have many activities and your project will not be ordered.

The other solution is implement one activity and many fragments depends of how many child you have. In your activity you only redirect the fragment depends of the child id.